# Call enum type with string

Tags: java, android, enums

I have an enumeration that contains elements like DOT_BLUE, DOT_YELLOW, SQUARE_BLUE, SQUARE_YELLOW etc. I also have a string, say String string = "DOT_BLUE". Now I want to access the enum depending on what the string is. I'm too lazy to write all the if else statements (there are a lot more elements) and using reflection in Java is tricky becuase I want to run this code on android aswell.

So is there any other more elegant way to access my enum depending on what the string is? I don't know of any, but I'm not a Java expert. So I'd be happy about a clear answer, even if it's "Nope".

Comment: Are you looking for `MyEnum.valueOf(name)`?

Comment: `using reflection in Java is tricky becuase I want to run this code on android aswell` why? there is nothing preventing you from using reflection in android.

Comment: I only said it is tricky, not impossible.

Comment: @Jon: I'm trying to understand the (very short) oracle documentation, but Ican't I'll try it out and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enums have a method valueOf(String name) in java 6 which can help you out.

JavaDoc says

"Returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the specified name. The name must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type."

Reference : [Class Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
public enum Color {

    DOT_BLUE, DOT_YELLOW, SQUARE_BLUE, SQUARE_YELLOW;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color color = Color.valueOf("DOT_BLUE");
        System.out.println(color.equals(Color.DOT_BLUE));
        System.out.println(color);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 but it would be nice to provide some explanation, not just code :)

Comment: let me put some explanation as well :)

Answer (score -1):

As Jon Skeet proposed you can use MyEnum.valueOf(name). Another option is to store a value for each enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    DOT_BLUE ("blue"),
    DOT_RED ("red");

    private String name;

    MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // provide a method to get the MyEnum based on some input
    public static MyEnum getByName(String name) {
        for (MyEnum myEnum : values()) {
            if (myEnum.getName().equals(name)) {
                return myEnum;
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum with the provided parameter");
        } 
    }

}
```

This option is more useful/powerful when you have more properties and want to find an Enum based on all of them/some of them.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement something like this.

```
enum Pattern {
   DOT_BLUE, DOT_YELLOW, SQUARE_BLUE, SQUARE_YELLOW;

   Pattern fromString(String code) {
       for(Pattern p : values()) {
           if(p.toString().equals(code)) return p
       }
       return null;
   }
}
```

Perhaps better if you implement a NULL_PATTERN and return it instead.  Also, if there are many values, you can cut the search time by creating an internal Map and do lookups.